# Problem with protobuf while migrating to gradle kotlin dls on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to migrate my project to [gradle kotlin dsl](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html). While doing this I faced a problem with protobuf. Before migration it was working as expected.

My `gradle.build.kts`:

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
    id("com.google.protobuf")
}

android {

  ...

  sourceSets {
    getByName("main") {
      proto {
        java.srcDir("src/main/java/com/...")
    }
  }

}


...

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.4"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.plugins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to sync project with gradle I got an error:

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file '.../build.gradle.kts' line: 37
Script compilation error:

  Line 37:             proto {
                       ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                           public fun SourceSet.proto(action: SourceDirectorySet.() -> Unit): Unit defined in com.google.protobuf.gradle
```

Answer (score 1):

(According to this link - https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/540)

Specify this function in your `gradle.build.kts`

```
fun AndroidSourceSet.proto(action: SourceDirectorySet.() -> Unit) {
    (this as? ExtensionAware)
        ?.extensions
        ?.getByName("proto")
        ?.let { it as? SourceDirectorySet }
        ?.apply(action)

}
```